# Wine fermenting with fruit in it after a month

Tags: wine

I have had a gallon of peach wine sitting in peach pulp for a little over a month. It is in a carboy with an airlock seal. Would it be okay to rack it and continue letting it age? Or did the continued presence of the fruit mess it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have limited experience with fermenting fruits except for the orange mead I make. I recently made a batch that I left on the fruit for more than 3 months. It tastes fantastic and is perfectly clear, bottling it this weekend. As long as you pasteurized the pulp and made sure everything was clean and sanitary, then I don't see how it could be messed up. You might get a more peachy flavour from it, but who doesn't like peaches? :)

Comment: Your answer gives me hope! But one thing.. I boiled the water to dissolve sugar, but I was following instructions that didn't say anything about pasteurization. About a week later I transferred it to a carboy. The bigger chunks were left behind leaving the peach pulp I'm referring to. All this is to say, no, it wasn't pasteurized.

Comment: I think it should be fine, easiest way is to give it a taste, if it tastes like its turned, then it's probably turned.